# EFCore return value when no data exists in table

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following method to return data from database:

```
public async Task<DentalHistoryModel> GetDentalHistoryAsync(int patientid)
        {
            DentalHistoryModel dentalHistory = new();
            using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {

                var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                try
                {
                    dentalHistory = await context.DentalHistory.Where(p => p.PatientId == patientid).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
            return dentalHistory;
        }
```

If there is no data in the DentalHistory table, what should be returned in dentalHistory? I am getting an empty dentalHistory object. Shouldn't I get a null in return?

Comment: Well, it seems as if the empty catch block might not be the best idea? What happened when you debugged it?

Comment: any reason doing `DentalHistoryModel dentalHistory = new();`? if you hit an error, you will get that instead of `null`. try remove the try-catch block and see what exception you are getting.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the issue. The table name was incorrect so it would have gone to the catch() block so I think it was returning an empty objected because I have that new statement in the beginning. Thanks.